# One parameter of custom class is re-written

Tags: c#, reflection, pinvoke

I have a custom class for triangles:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlType("Figure.Triangle")]
public class Triangle : Figure
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Point a { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Point b { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Point c { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("a")]
    public string aString
    {
        get { return a.X.ToString() + ';' + a.Y.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                return;
            string[] xmlArr = value.Split(';');
            this.a = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(xmlArr[0]), Convert.ToInt32(xmlArr[1]));
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("b")]
    public string bString
    {
        get { return b.X.ToString() + ';' + b.Y.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                return;
            string[] xmlArr = value.Split(';');
            this.b = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(xmlArr[0]), Convert.ToInt32(xmlArr[1]));
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("c")]
    public string cString
    {
        get { return c.X.ToString() + ';' + c.Y.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                return;
            string[] xmlArr = value.Split(';');
            this.c = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(xmlArr[0]), Convert.ToInt32(xmlArr[1]));
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Pen pen { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("PenColor")]
    public int penColor
    {
        get { return pen.Color.ToArgb(); }
        set { this.pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(value); }
    }

    [XmlElement("PenWidth")]
    public float penWidth
    {
        get { return this.pen.Width; }
        set { this.pen.Width = value; }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public SolidBrush brush { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("BrushColor")]
    public int brushColor
    { 
        get { return this.brush.Color.ToArgb();}
        set { this.brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(value); }
    }
    public Triangle()
    {
        a = new Point(0, 0);
        b = new Point(0, 0);
        c = new Point(0, 0);
        pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    }

    public Triangle(Point a1, Point b1, Point c1, Pen myPen)
    {
        this.a = a1;
        this.b = b1;
        this.c = c1;
        this.pen = myPen;
    }
}
```

I serialize my figures to the xml-structure and save them. If I need I deserialize them back and re-draw in the pictureBox.
The issue is: when I deserialize figures from xml, all filled figures have the color of the last one.

Here's part of deserialization:

```
foreach (XmlNode singleNode in nodes)
{
    Type TestType = GetTypeFromAssemblyByName(singleNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("d1p1:type").Value);
    if (TestType != null)
    {
        ConstructorInfo ci = TestType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
        object Obj = ci.Invoke(new object[] { });
        MethodInfo method = TestType.GetMethod("Deserialize");
        object result = method.Invoke(Obj, new object[] { singleNode.OuterXml });                      
        listObjects.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class wasn't found");
    }
}
```

E.g. I have 2 filled triangles which are saved to Xml. First is blue and second is red and both of them have different brush color, which is need for fillPolygon method.

```
<Workspace>
  <Figure d1p1:type="Figure.FilledTriangle" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a>64;68</a>
    <b>96;295</b>
    <c>283;41</c>
    <PenColor>-16777216</PenColor>
    <PenWidth>1</PenWidth>
    <BrushColor>-16744193</BrushColor>
  </Figure>
  <Figure d1p1:type="Figure.FilledTriangle" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a>321;411</a>
    <b>575;152</b>
    <c>629;462</c>
    <PenColor>-16777216</PenColor>
    <PenWidth>1</PenWidth>
    <BrushColor>-65408</BrushColor>
  </Figure>
</Workspace>
```

Everything seems right, but when I invoke the Deserialize method, the result is, that the brush color of all previously added figures in the list is re-written. So in my example I have two red triangles on theirs right positions.

I understand that list contains references to the result, but other parameters: coordinates, pen color, etc are left as they were.

How can I get rid of this? I've tried to write result values to array, but even in the array they were replaced.

*Update 1*
Deserialize method which I use:

```
public class Serializer<T> where T : class
{
    public T Deserialize(string inputXml)
    {
        try
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(inputXml))
            {
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)xs.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error was caught during deserialization " + ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for your `Deserialize` method?

Comment: Don't store objects like Pen and SolidBrush in your class.  They should be created only just before you need them, at painting time, with a *using* statement that disposes them again.  Solves this bug as well.

Comment: @BrianRogers:
I don't think this method is  guilty because in result I've got right values, but anyway I've just updated my post with Deserialize method

Comment: @HansPassant: How can I store pens and brushes colors them? I'm working on some kind on Paint application, so I need to open my workspace wilth all figures later.

Comment: Store colors, not brushes and pens.  You create those only when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are assigning the same pen to different figures. If you change the color of a pen in one figure, this changes the color in all these figures. Instead of changing the color of a pen, create a new pen. This is true for the line widths as well:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Pen pen { get; set; }
[XmlElement("PenColor")]
public int penColor
{
    get { return pen.Color.ToArgb(); }
    set { pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(value), pen.Width); }
}

[XmlElement("PenWidth")]
public float penWidth
{
    get { return pen.Width; }
    set { pen = new Pen(pen.Color, value); }
}
```

The brushes should be treated the same way.

---

Or, as Hans Passant suggests, create the pens and brushes as you need them and store only their attributes.

```
[XmlElement("PenColor")]
public int penColor { get; set; }

[XmlElement("PenWidth")]
public float penWidth  { get; set; }

public Pen CreatePen()
{
    return new Pen(Color.FromArgb(penColor), penWidth);
}
```

Usage:

```
using (Pen pen = figure.CreatePen()){
    graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 10, 50);
    ...
}
```

Declaring a method with the word "Create" in its name, instead of property, makes it clear that a new pen is created at each call and that the pen should be disposed after usage, as does the using-statement.

Note that pens and brushes are not thread safe. If you want to speed up things by rendering bitmaps in the background in different threads, you must create these objetcs in the same thread as they are used. Changes made in another thread will result in an exception, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I've rewrited getters-setters and that helped.